# Discrete Math - Recursive Relation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Passwords for a certain computer system are strings of uppercase letters. A valid password must contain an even number of X’s. Determine a recurrence relation for the number of valid passwords of length n. Note: 0 is an even number, so ABBC is a valid password.

Here’s a good way to think about it: to make a good password of length n you can either:

(a) add any non-X to the end of a good password of length n − 1, or

(b) add an X to the end of a bad password of length n − 1. For (b) you can use the Good = Total-Bad trick to count the number of bad passwords of length n−1.

*This is for an Introductory Discrete math course, so any sort of coding will not be helpful and I will not understand.

I also need to figure out the recursive solution for Xn, so if Xn+1 is shown, I have yet to understand how it applies to the recursive solution Xn. If you could PLEASE give me a STEP-FOR-STEP explanation on how this problem and the clues help answer this (throw in some examples as well), it would be so helpful to me. One thing for sure is I do not understand the n-1 part in the clues and how that applies to answering the question. Thus far, I have come up with Xn= 24(x(n-1)) + 26^(n-1), but when I set n=1, I end up with 1, which from using paper and pencil, is not correct (x1 should equal 25, not zero)*

Comment: $x_0 = 1$ not $0$.  There is one valid string of length zero, the empty string: " "

Answer (score 1):

Let $G(n)$ represent the number of **G**ood strings of length $n$, that is the number of strings where there are an even number of X's.

Let $B(n)$ represent the number of **B**ad strings of length $n$, that is the number of strings where there are an odd number of X's.

Let $T(n)$ represent the **T**otal number of strings of length $n$.

It should be clear that $T(n) = G(n)+B(n) = 26^n$, seen from multiplication principle and induction.

It should also be clear that $T(1)=26$, that $G(1)=25$ and $B(1)=1$.  Alternatively, you could note that $T(0)=G(0)=1$ and $B(0)=0$.  These will be our "seed" values.

---

We try to come up with a recursive definition for $G(n)$.  To do this, we suppose that we do not know the value for $G(n)$ for the input of $n$ specifically, but we know the value for all inputs strictly less than $n$ (*in particular for $n-1$*).

We recognize that we can count how many good strings of length $n$ there are from the fact that we can construct every good string of length $n$ by using smaller strings.  As the hint in the problem suggests, we break into cases based on what the final character of the string is.

Any good string of length $n$ falls into exactly one of the following cases:

- The last character is not an X and the prefix string made up of all characters except the last one is a "good string" of length $n-1$ (*which we know exactly how many there are as per our induction hypothesis*).  There are exactly $25\times G(n-1)$ such strings in this case (*pick what the last non-X character it is, and pick which prefix it is, apply multiplication principle*).
- The last character *is* an X and the prefix string made up of all characters except the last one is a "bad string" of length $n-1$ (*which we know exactly how many there are as per our induction hypothesis*).  There are exactly $1\times B(n-1)$ such strings in this case (*set the last character as X and then pick which prefix it is, apply multiplication principle*).

Noting there is no overlap between the cases and noting that these cases are exhaustive and cover all possibilities, we get the following:

$$G(n) = 25\times G(n-1) + 1\times B(n-1)$$

Remembering that $T(n-1) = G(n-1) + B(n-1) = 26^{n-1}$ we can rewrite the $B(n-1)$ from the above as:

$$G(n) = 25\times G(n-1) + (26^{n-1} - G(n-1))$$
$$G(n) = 24\times G(n-1) + 26^{n-1}$$

In your post you wrote "*But when I set $n=1$, I end up with $1$...*"

$G(1) = 24\times G(1-1) + 26^{1-1} = 24\times G(0) + 26^0 = 24\times 1 + 1 = 25$ as expected.  Remember that $G(0)=1$.  You probably incorrectly assumed $G(0)=0$.  The [empty-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string) is technically considered to be a string, just like how the empty set is considered to be a set.  There is exactly one string of length zero and it has an even number of X's (*zero X's to be specific*) so it counts as a good string in our problem.

---

If you wanted to you could continue the problem and come up with a closed form solution for $G(n)$ which is not recursive.  At a glance, it will be of the form $G(n) = c\cdot 24^n + d\cdot 26^n$ for some constants $c,d$ which would take some algebra to find.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!  I did have one question in relation to G(n)=25×G(n−1)+1×B(n−1).  Shouldn't it be T(n)=25×G(n−1)+1×B(n−1) instead of G(n)=25×G(n−1)+1×B(n−1).  To me, the one provided would actually equal the total number of passwords, not the number of good passwords.  Am I missing something with regards to how notation is being used?

Comment: It is indeed *only* the good that it counts.  T(n) = 26 T(n-1) = 26 G(n-1) + 26 B(n-1) is strictly greater than the above.  In constructing G(n) using smaller strings, we either took an even number of Xs in the prefix and attached a non-X to the end, even+0 is still even,  or we took a prefix with an odd number of Xs and add one X to the end, odd+1=even.  In both cases we end with an even number of Xs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding a recursion formula (of recursion level one), let us give an exact formula (which is a recursion of level zero).

The alphabet has $25$ (upper) letters $\ne X$, and also this $X$:
Consider the binomial expansion of
$$
(25+X)^n\ .
$$
If counts in degree $k$ (i.e. the coefficient of $X^k$ is) the number of words/passwords with exactly $k$ occurences of $X$. (Because the noncommutative expansion of $(A+B+\dots+W+Y+Z\qquad +X)^n$ "shows" all words, and then we formally set $A=B=\dots=W=Y=Z=1$.)
To isolate all those words with an even number of $X$'s, and prepair them for the counter we build:
$$\frac 12\Big(\ (25+X)^n+(25-X)^n\ \Big)\ .$$
Now we set $X=1$, getting the counter
$$C(n)=\frac 12\left( 26^n+24^n\right)\ .$$

---

Examples: $C(0)=1$, the empty password, in accordance with the formula. $C(1)=(26+24)/2=25$, yes, the one-letter-$X$-password is forbidden.
$C(2)$ counts the password $XX$, and all $\alpha\beta$ with two $\alpha,\beta$ non-$X$-letters. This is also $\frac 12(26^2+24^2)=\frac 12((25+1)^2+(25-1)^2)=\frac 12\sum_\pm(25^2\pm2\cdot25+1 ^2)=25^2+1^2=C(2)$.